# ECSlidingViewController UITabBarController setTopViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

I am using an open source to handle Facebook style sliding menu.
I am getting the exception below.

```
UITabBarController setTopViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I am using ARC, Storyboard, XCode 4.5 and a `UITabController`.
What it was trying to do is setting a viewController. 
Vc is not null.

It is trying set a view controller to below and thrown an error.
ExploreViewController embedded in Navigation Controller and also `UITabBarController`.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *topViewController;
```

Here is my code.

```
ECSlidingViewController *slidingViewController = (ECSlidingViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UIStoryboard *storyboard;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
} else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPad" bundle:nil];
}
UIViewController *vc= [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ExploreViewController"];
slidingViewController.topViewController = vc; //exception thrown here.
```

Comment: Does anyone has any experience with sliding menu that works with storyboard, tab bar, navigation?

Comment: Have you resolved this problem

Comment: If you have resolved this problem, please paste your code how to add ecslideviewcontroller to UITabbarcontroller as top vc